# Implicit conversions with template classes

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, implicit-conversion

I'm trying to define a class template that can do some input/output operations (via operators << and >> from another class) on many data structures.

In short, I can do for example :

```
vector<int> x;
map<string,vector<vector<int>>> y;
const int z = 42;

FooStream fs;

Foo<decltype(x)> fx(x);
Foo<decltype(y)> fy(y);
Foo<decltype(z)> fz(z);

fs << fx << fy << fz >> fy >> fx;
```

My question is how can I reach this :

```
vector<int> x;
map<string,vector<vector<int>>> y;
const int z = 42;

FooStream fs;

fs << x << y << z >> y >> x;
//error : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::vector<_Ty>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

FooStream::operator<< and >> should accept ever type T when the specialization Foo< T> is defined.

For more details, here's my (simplified) code.

```
class FooBase1{
protected:
    union p_type{const void *p1;void *p2;} p;
public:
    FooBase1(const void *v){p.p1 = v;};
    virtual void func1_() = 0;
};

class FooBase2 : public FooBase1{
public:
    FooBase2(void *v) : FooBase1(v){};
    virtual void func2_() = 0;
};

template<typename T,typename Enable=void>
class Foo{
public:
    typedef void generic;
};

template<typename T,typename E=void> struct is_generic                             : std::false_type{};
template<typename T>                 struct is_generic<T,typename Foo<T>::generic> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T,typename T2=void> struct enable_if_ng  : enable_if<!is_generic<T>::value,T2> {};

template<typename T> struct get_foo_type          {};
template<typename T> struct get_foo_type<Foo<T> > {typedef T type;};

#define DECLARE_FOO_SPECIALIZATION(Type)\
template<>\
class Foo<Type> : public FooBase2{\
public:\
    Foo(Type &v) : FooBase2(&v){}\
    virtual void func1_(){func1(*(const Type *)p.p2);}\
    virtual void func2_(){func2(*(Type *)p.p2);}\
    static void func1(const Type&){/*user defined*/}\
    static void func2(Type&){/*user defined*/}\
};
    //friend FooStream& operator>>(FooStream& fs,Type &f){Foo<Type>(f).func2_();return fs;} doesn't work

DECLARE_FOO_SPECIALIZATION(bool)
DECLARE_FOO_SPECIALIZATION(int)
DECLARE_FOO_SPECIALIZATION(long)
DECLARE_FOO_SPECIALIZATION(float)
DECLARE_FOO_SPECIALIZATION(double)
DECLARE_FOO_SPECIALIZATION(string)

template<typename T1>
class Foo<vector<T1>,typename enable_if_ng<T1>::type> : public FooBase2{
public:
    Foo(vector<T1> &v) : FooBase2(&v){}
    virtual void func1_(){func1(*(const vector<T1> *)p.p2);}
    virtual void func2_(){func2(*(vector<T1> *)p.p2);}
    static void func1(const vector<T1>&){/*user defined*/}
    static void func2(vector<T1>&){/*user defined*/}
};

template<typename T1,typename T2>
class Foo<map<T1,T2>,typename enable_if<!is_generic<T1>::value && !is_generic<T2>::value>::type> : public FooBase2{
public:
    Foo(map<T1,T2> &v) : FooBase2(&v){}
    virtual void func1_(){func1(*(const map<T1,T2> *)p.p2);}
    virtual void func2_(){func2(*(map<T1,T2> *)p.p2);}
    static void func1(const map<T1,T2>&){/*user defined*/}
    static void func2(map<T1,T2>&){/*user defined*/}
};

template<typename T1>
class Foo<const T1,typename enable_if_ng<T1>::type> : public FooBase1{
public:
    Foo(const T1 &v) : FooBase1(&v){}
    virtual void func1_(){func1(*(const T1 *)p.p1);}
    static void func1(const T1& v){Foo<T1>::func1(v);}
};

class FooStream{
public:
    FooStream(){};
    FooStream& operator<<(FooBase1 &f){f.func1_();return *this;};
    FooStream& operator>>(FooBase2 &f){f.func2_();return *this;};
};
```

(Additional questions : can I replace my macro DECLARE_FOO_SPECIALIZATION by something prettier with templates ? Should I change my class hierarchy ?)

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you can try to use parenthesis to order the evaluation.

Comment: Post name needs fixing up. It's not related to the post.

Comment: @0x499602D2 : the operators << and >> are evaluated from left to right. But I have the same error message when I put only 1 parameter.

Comment: @Mr Universe : sorry I've just changed it, but do you have a better suggestion ?

Comment: @Gilles i dont know exactly whats going on in there. All i can say is operators work right to left and it could be that at some point you have the wrong operator.

Comment: @Gilles to see if I understand the question before writing an answer, is it [something like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=4bd11a1c79960bdaae2e365925eb9152-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba) you are looking for? IF a specialization of `template<typename T> struct FooObj;` is present you are allowed to pass a `T` to `FooStream::operator<</>>`

Comment: @Gilles the example is a bit meh.. `is_object` will give you a cleaner error than `is_constructible`, it will also aid future code maintenance.

Comment: Yes this fits perfectly what i wanted to do ! I have been slow to respond but I have considered your answers carefully and that was very helpful. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `EnableIf` doesn't work in many compilers, but you can use a more crude SFINAE trick there:

```
template<std::size_t n>
struct secret_enum { enum class type {}; };
template<bool b, std::size_t n = 0>
using EnableIf = typename std::enable_if< b, typename secret_enum<n>::type >::type;

template<typename T, bool b=true>
struct can_be_fooed : std::false_type {};
template<typename T>
struct can_be_fooed<T, std::is_same<Foo<T>, Foo<T>>::value>:std::true_type {};

class FooStream{
public:

  template<typename T, EnableIf<can_be_fooed<typename std::decay<T>::type>>...>
  FooStream& operator<<(T&&t){
    // body of <<, possibly involving wrapping the t in a Foo<T>?
  };
};
```

---

When testing this kind of code, stop doing 15 things on one line when the first one would fail.  Test things a single step at a time.  With template meta programming, you are debugging the compilation step -- by compiling things in byte sized chunks and checking at each step, you are doing the equivalent of stepping through your code.

---

Instead of your macro, create a traits class where the elements in question are the only ones that have a `true`.  Then just use SFINAE to write one `template` that is turned on for only those types.  Same number of lines of code, but no code generated by macro.

```
template<typename T> struct do_stuff : std::false_type {};
template<> struct do_stuff<int> : std::true_type {};
template<> struct do_stuff<bool> : std::true_type {};
// yada yada

template<typename T>
class Foo<T, typename=typename std::enable_if< do_stuff<T>::value >::type> : public FooBase2 {
public:
  Foo(T &v) : FooBase2(&v){}
  virtual void func1_(){func1(*(const T *)p.p2);}
  virtual void func2_(){func2(*(T *)p.p2);}\
  static void func1(const T&){/*user defined*/}\
  static void func2(T&){/*user defined*/}\
};
```